# seaborn.kdeplot (pandas.DataFrame) - ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to make a `kdeplot` for my pandas dataframe. I used the code below:

```
mean = [0,0]

cov = [[1,0],[0,100]]

dataset2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,1000)

dframe = pd.DataFrame(dataset2,columns=['X','Y'])

sns.kdeplot(dframe)
```

And got this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-852468cc1da8> in <module>()
      7 dframe = pd.DataFrame(dataset2,columns=['X','Y'])
      8 
----> 9 sns.kdeplot(dframe)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in extract_index(data)
    385 
    386         if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
--> 387             raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
    388 
    389         if have_series:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

How should I amend my code?

Note: It works when I instead use:

```
sns.kdeplot(dframe.X,dframe.Y)
```

Comment: `sns.kdeplot(dframe)` is not valid syntax, as per [`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html). You have not properly specified the parameters in order.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So, the code I wrote seems to be deprecated because it worked before (according to a Udemy course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign the columns to the plot

```
sns.kdeplot(data=dframe,x='X',y='Y')
```